# iOS9 open other app first pop up alertView,get the cancel button callBack

Tags: objective-c, ios9

iOS9 open another app by urlSchemes first will pop up the confirm alertView.How to get the callBack when press the cancel Button.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]];`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1t0b.png

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: I have update the code and screen shot.TKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alan pointed out himself, the following `UIApplicationDelegate` methods can be used to determine the stats of the `openURL` `UIAlertView`:

- Alert view is shown: `applicationWillResignActive`
- User chooses open URL, and it leads to the actual app switching: `applicationDidEnterBackground`
- Alert view is cancelled or app is switched back: `is-processing-app-switching` will be called

I guess a flag like "is-processing-app-switching" based on `NSUserDefaults` can be set to `true` before the `openURL` call, and when it's true `applicationDidEnterBackground` can be used to determined if user chooses cancel or not. In `is-processing-app-switching` the flag should be set to false. This workaround seems ugly to me but when you really want to determine the stats of the build in `UIAlertView`, at least is doable.

Thanks the poster again for figuring out a solution himself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to confirm before performing the action:

```
- (void)openAppAfterConfirmation
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Open App?"
                                                                   message:@"OK to open app, Cancel to "
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

                                                       //do the CANCEL stuff here
                                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *confirm = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

                                                        //do the CONFIRM stuff here
                                                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]];
                                                    }];

    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [alert addAction:confirm];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm not mean this.[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]] will pop up the confirm alertView auto by iOS9 system.I can't get the alertView.

Comment: Whats the problem then? Everything would work according to iOS 9 default

Comment: When call the `OpenURL` methods, the alertView pop up iOS9 default.I need the cancel button pressed callBack.

Comment: Yes this answer is not relevant. The alert view is triggered by iOS 9, and I'm looking for the callback as well.

Comment: @superarts.org  I found that when the alertView pop up. The method `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` will be call in `AppDelegate`

Comment: @Alan are you sure about that? I tested and the `applicationWillTerminate` is only triggered when the app is actually switched, i.e. you select "open" in the alert view. At the point the alert view is shown and / or "cancel" is tapped, no `UIApplicationDelegate` events are triggered.

Comment: @superarts.org. Sorry,I'm confuse.  `shown->applicationWillResignActive`, `cancel->applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: Thanks @Alan yes it is as you said!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of making a call, to control when the user touch the Cancel or Call button I'm using the CXCallObserver from the CallKit framework to detect calls changes.

Also add an observer to capture when the app is becoming active after coming back from the call request.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    // If queue is nil, then callbacks will be performed on main queue
    [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    // Don't forget to store reference to callObserver, to prevent it from being released
    self.callObserver = callObserver;

    // Add an observer on application become active and set a selector to perform
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleAppBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object :nil];

}
```

Here we delegate the changes of call states.

```
#pragma mark - CXCallObserverDelegate Delegate
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.outgoing) {
        // Set flag to true
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"on-going-call"];
    }

}
```

`handleAppBecomeActive` selector to perform when the observer react to the:

> UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

```
- (void)handleAppBecomeActive {
    // Get flag
    bool onGoingCall = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:"on-goin-call"];

    if (onGoingCall) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"on-going-call"];
        // The user chose the Call action, do something
    }
}
```

It's not too fancy, but it can help detect when the user selects an action when calling the method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://111111111"]];
```